# How to clear an alarm when a minimum is reached?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have working autoscaling up and down for ecs containers. I have a minimum of 1 and various maximums setup and these work with my cpu threshold based alarms. But when they are idle, after scaling down to 1, the alarm remains, i.e. it is not in OK status, it's red. From the alarm's point of view, it is explainable, cpu is below the threshold. The policy is working correctly, it lowers the count until the minimum is hit.

I just don't want that alarm! What are you all doing as this has to be a common case?